# Creating a function to be used in the where clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Every day I have to run lots of adhoc queries and all of these queries has the same condition in the where clause.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a function or an alias or something to make it easy and fast to write the queries.

Usually the queries are something like:

```
select * 
from tbl_1
where customer in ('ctm1','ctm2','ctmetc')
and isnull(status,'c') in (select status from tbl_status)
```

What I was wondering is if is possible to develop something like:

```
select * 
from tbl_1
where customer in ('ctm1','ctm2','ctmetc')
and function.status = 'C'
```

in which function.status = 'C' reffers to "isnull(status,'c') in (select status from tbl_status)"

I did a lot of research but nothing had helped...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could write such a function, but it would kill performance.

Comment: I'm thinking about give it a go and compare both performances. Maybe the difference is acceptable. thanks @GordonLinoff

Comment: It would be better if you write a table-valued function to solve all queries just receiving parameters

Comment: @Horaciux, an iTVF won't even help here. With very few exceptions, you want to avoid using functions on any filter columns in the WHERE predicate. Even the use of built in functions, like ISNULL will prevent a seek operation.

Comment: @JasonA.Long I mean using it in `FROM`, not as `WHERE` condition. I consider them as a parameterized views. OP post an XY problem, I'm trying to solve the subjacent problem, not the attempted solution.

Comment: @Horaciux - Sure that's where you add the function, but there's no point in adding it if you aren't going to filter the function's output in the predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way to look at this.  The stated problem is that you have to type the same string over and over again.

I suggest looking at a way to automate the typing.  There are utilities out there to solve this problem.  The one I use is called [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/).  There might be others out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

If by acceptable, you mean forcing a table/index scan 100% of the time (Even if other parts of the predicate allow a seek, you'll still have a range scan on status). Then by all means give it a go. Of course the current use of ISNULL is doing the same thing, so you're likely not going to make things worse. The proper (or at least SARGEible) way to write it would be to write it like the following...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.tbl_1 t1
WHERE
    t1.customer IN ( 'ctm1', 'ctm2', 'ctmetc' )
    AND (
            t1.Status IS NULL
            OR 
            EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tbl_status s WHERE t1.status = s.status)
        );

-- OR --

SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.tbl_1 t1
WHERE
    t1.customer IN ( 'ctm1', 'ctm2', 'ctmetc' )
    AND (
            t1.Status IS NULL
            OR 
            t1.Status IN (SELECT s.Status FROM dbo.tbl_status s)
        );
```

Comment: Let me be more specific: I have a table called tbl_status with 2 columns and  10 rows. Every adhoc query I have to check is in the main table the status in the tbl_status using ISNULL. As I always repeat the same clause, I was wondering to simplify the code creating a function so instead of write the whole clause " and isnull(status,'c') in (select status from tbl_status) I would just write something like " and dbo.func_status = 'C'

Comment: @RFerreira - That's fine, but can you say the same for tbl_1?... Because that's the one that's going to eat the scan (or at the very least a range scan).

Comment: tbl_1 has lots of data, hundreds of thousands, but if scanning just a range, I won't have performance degradation... I'm writing a code and if works fine I'll post here.

Comment: If you have a suitable index on Customer and ( 'ctm1', 'ctm2', 'ctmetc' ) is selective enough (aka those 3 customers aren't the bulk of that table). You should he a seek based on that part of the predicate. It just seems silly to me to eat a range scan if it isn't necessary.

Comment: Yeap, not happy with the function. I'm closing this topic. Thank's guys.